# Break the undo sequence in normal mode

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, undo-redo

**Question:** Is there something which is works same as [i_CTRL-G_u](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-G_u), but for **normal mode**?

This would be useful in mappings (like `nnoremap`), because (I think, but fixme) in normal mode, if you are just typing commands (vs. a sequence mapped to a single key), then each command counts as a separate undo block.

**Case in point:** I'm trying to solve [this exercise](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/29.html#extra-credit), from Learn Vimscript the Hard Way.

This is what I came up with, and it seems to work:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d ddi<C-G>u<esc>dd
```

While this works, it seems a bit hackish, going into insert mode *just to break the undo sequence*, so I was wondering if it is possible without going into insert mode.

Of course, I already tried the following variant, but all it does is deleting a single line, so it seems that the `<C-G>` part kind of ends the sequence:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d dd<C-G>udd
```

Comment: I nixed the spoiler—I'm not concerned about sharing the code, and it's important that the question is easy to read. If others feel strongly opposed, we can discuss

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could try this: `nnoremap <leader>d dd@=execute('let &ul = &ul')[-1]<cr>dd`.  But technically, it still temporarily leaves normal mode to enter the command-line (the expression one).  See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26475/17449.

Comment: "It seems a bit hackish, going into insert mode just to break the undo sequence." Welcome to Vimscript! You seem to be learning the actual lessons about it! 

Answer (score 6):

Doing `:let &ul=&ul` breaks the undo sequence. This is documented under `:h :undojoin`:

> Setting the value of 'undolevels' also breaks undo.  Even when the new value
> is equal to the old value.

Using the described method, you can do the following:

```
nnoremap <leader>d dd:let &ul=&ul<CR>dd
```

Comment: This is documented at the end of [:h :undoj](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#:undoj).  More specifically [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/57ad94c5a9ee6f3626e1ec728519a8558a4346c8/runtime/doc/undo.txt#L112-L113).

Comment: @user938271 thanks, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Most elegant in my opinion:

```
nnoremap <leader>dd :call feedkeys("dddd",'t')<cr>
```

`feedkeys()` function with `'t'` parameter pretends that the user actually typed `dddd`.

If you press `dddd` in Normal mode, you can undo first `dd`, and then second `dd`. If you create a mapping for that and use it, `u` undoes the whole mapped sequence at once, which is the problem introduced in the question. However, once you create a mapping using `feedkeys()` function with `'t'` parameter as in my example, you can undo each individual normal mode command from a sequence of normal mode commands given as first argument to the `feedkeys()` function.

Of course you cannot control the "granularity" of breaking the undo-sequence using this method. But for some uses it may be more elegant and readable.

More info: `:help feedkeys()`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! How does this address breaking the undo-sequence, which was the main thrust of the question?

Comment: If you press `dddd` in Normal mode, you can undo first `dd`, and then second `dd`. If you create a mapping for that and use it, `u` undoes the whole mapped sequence at once, which is the problem introduced in the question. However, once you create a mapping using `feedkeys()` function with `'t'` parameter as in my example, you can undo each individual normal mode command from a sequence of normal mode commands given as first argument to the `feedkeys()` function.

Comment: Of course you cannot control the "granularity" of breaking the undo-sequence using this method. But for some uses it may be more elegant and readable.

Comment: That information should really make its way into the answer; it would be much stronger that way. Feel free to [edit].